# How to change the Menu dropdown element from Select in MaterialUI?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

What I need to do is actually change the HTML from the select dropdown when the property multiple is true, to be something like this:

[image]

Don't need to be exactly like that, the main thing that I want to do is add the checkbox before the option label. I can't see a way of doing this because the select component only accepts a MenuProps prop instead accepting a MenuComponent as well..

The select component docs:
https://material-ui.com/pt/components/selects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can do that with the Select component without having to modify it a lot, but you can use [Autocomplete](https://material-ui.com/components/autocomplete/#checkboxes) which has pretty much the same functionality and you can add checkboxes to it.

Comment: I never thought about autocomplete, but it's pretty much what I want, thanks!